# How can I style my table header based upon table html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Using Ckeditor there are two possible html of table without header and second one is with header. Now I want to style only one top row of table, I don't care if it is a thead row or tbody row. Below is code for both case.

Without Header:

```
<table class="smart-table">
    <colgroup cols="2">
        <col colnum="1" colname="1" width="486.00px">
        <col colnum="2" colname="2" width="486.00px">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="smart-table-row">
            <td class="smart-table-cell"><div data-qxe-element="p" class="p">
                    <br>
                </div></td>
            <td class="smart-table-cell"><div data-qxe-element="p" class="p">
                    <br>
                </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="smart-table-row">
            <td class="smart-table-cell"><div data-qxe-element="p" class="p">
                    <br>
                </div></td>
            <td class="smart-table-cell"><div data-qxe-element="p" class="p">
                    <br>
                </div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With Header:

```
<table class="smart-table">
    <colgroup cols="2">
        <col colnum="1" colname="1" width="486.00px">
        <col colnum="2" colname="2" width="486.00px">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr class="smart-table-row">
            <th class="smart-table-cell"><div data-qxe-element="p" class="p">
                    <br>
                </div></th>
            <th class="smart-table-cell"><div data-qxe-element="p" class="p">
                    <br>
                </div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="smart-table-row">
            <td class="smart-table-cell"><div data-qxe-element="p" class="p">
                    <br>
                </div></td>
            <td class="smart-table-cell"><div data-qxe-element="p" class="p">
                    <br>
                </div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS I am using below:

```
.table  thead tr:first-child th {
    background-color: #004b92;
    color:White;  
}

.table  tbody tr:first-child td {
    background-color: #004b92;
    color:White;  
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: it is not clear from your question what is that you want. You have clearly stated what you know but have not stated what is the problem.

Comment: I have one simple objective color first row of table. Now i have two possible table html stated above. I am expecting something in css which work in a way if there is thead apply css on first row of thead if not then apply css on first row of tbody. I want to do it all using css only if possible.

Answer (score -1):

For this you will have to use a bit jQuery. First find all tables generated by CKEditor and apply a css class on them by below script.

```
$(function() {
    fnApplyHeaderClass();
});

var fnApplyHeaderClass = function() {

    $("table.smart-table").each(function() {

        if ($(this).find("thead").length > 0) {

            $(this).find("thead").find("tr").eq(0).addClass("ck-editor-header");
        } else {
            $(this).find("tbody").find("tr").eq(0).addClass("ck-editor-header");
        }
    });

};
```

and in CSS, use this

```
.ck-editor-header{    
  background-color: #004b92;
  color:White;  
}
```

Working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/00qbtsf7/

Comment: Thank you for reply. yes i am able to do it the way you stated but i want to try it with css only if that is not possible then i will move to your approach.